# Setting up WordPress protocol using Softaculous & Namecheap

Tags: https

I am setting up WordPress on my new Namecheap domain/hosting account and the site I am building will eventually be offering items for sale (a small personal business site selling vintage items). I'm learning about SSL certificates now - I've seen some advice to choose `https://` and some to choose the `http://` option because the SSL certificate will take care of the rest. There are 4 protocol options when setting up WordPress via Softaculous, and I'm not sure which one to choose:

```
- `http://`
- `http://www`
- `https://`
- `https://www`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a small personal e-commerce website, you will probably want to choose a simple payment method such as PayPal or similar.

If this is the case, payments are handled on the PayPal website and you probably won't need an SSL certificate or https on your website.

This reduces the choices down to `"http://"` or `"http://www"`. Either is suitable. I prefer a shorter url so would tend to choose the `"http://"` option. Either way, and to avoid the duplicate content penalty from Google, you should redirect the www version of the website to the non-www version of the website or vice versa. This can be done in cPanel via the "Redirects" option.

Comment: thanks for the information and the added info about the redirects - much appreciated @neil!